# Income tax on selling stock bought at various times

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax

Say I have 24 shares of stock X, and I got these shares by buying 1 share every month for 2 years. If I now want to sell 1 share of X, how will I know if it is a share I bought 2 years ago, 12 months ago, last month, etc? Basically, if I just sell a share of X, then how will I know if the share being sold was bought more than a year ago. I would like to avoid paying income tax on the share. I am in the United States.

Comment: Shares are fungible. Typically you would decide "which" share you sold in order to minimise tax, or even defer the tax to a more suitable time.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie That's true, but you have to decide by the time you sell the share (either by modifying the broker's default beforehand or specifying at time of sale, if the broker allows those). You can't sell, then next April decide which share you sold.

Answer (score 5):

This is U.S.-specific since I don't know the rules in other countries. Are you in the U.S.?

You can select specific shares to sell within your brokerage account, and you may have to change the selling rule to "specific shares/lot" to do that. Otherwise, most platforms will default to first-in-first-out (FIFO) or minimum tax impact (MinTax). If minimizing current-year taxes is the goal, MinTax should achieve that without needing to select specific tax lots.

Comment: I am in the US. Just added it to the question.

Comment: That presumes your broker offers a MinTax process. Note that mostly what this does (assuming you aren't within the short-term-gains window) is shift *when* the tax is due. Which may be useful if you you can move the gains enough to take them under a lower tax bracket. But that requires a lot more effort than I want to put into managing my money, and the improvement is generally minimal unless you're realizing huge gains or have a huge change in other tax variables.